# Find groupings of numeric subsets

Tags: python, set, intersection

Lets say I have these numeric sets

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
b = {2, 3, 4}
c = {1, 5}
```

I want to find all distinct numeric groupings of the sets. The result would be

```
{1}, {2, 3}, {4}, {5}
```

My naive approach, which doesn't work, is something like this:

```
data = [{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 5}]
for i in range(1, 5):
    s = set.intersection(*[x for x in data if i in x])
    print(s)
```

Which returns

```
set([1])
set([2, 3])
set([2, 3])
set([2, 3, 4])
```

Which could be easily de-duplicated but doesn't give the expected result.

How can I get only the groupings of numbers that exist in subset of sets?

Comment: Not sure your algorithm works. You probably want to go through the 2^3-1 subsets of [0,1,2] and look which are the elements that appear in each subset and not in the complementary

Comment: Can you clarify `groupings of numbers that exist in subset of sets` a bit further? What's your idea of `distinct numeric grouping`? Because `{1}`, `{4}` and `{5}` are certainly not groups of any kind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

- You stop at `5`, but `range` doesn't include the stop so you don't check for 5.
- If a value is only in one set you need to create a set that only contains that value. At least your expected result looks as if that's the desired behaviour.

So by fixing these issues the code would look like this:

```
data = [{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 5}]
for i in range(1, 6):
    useful_sets = [x for x in data if i in x]
    if len(useful_sets) <= 1:
        print(set([i]))
    else:
        s = set.intersection(*useful_sets)
        print(s)

# prints:
# {1}
# {2, 3}
# {2, 3}
# {4}
# {5}
```

To get a complete (and not duplicated) result you could store them as frozensets in a set:

```
data = [{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1, 5}]
res = set()
for i in range(1, 6):
    useful_sets = [x for x in data if i in x]
    if len(useful_sets) <= 1:
        res.add(frozenset([i]))
    else:
        s = set.intersection(*useful_sets)
        res.add(frozenset(s))

print(res)
# {frozenset({5}), frozenset({4}), frozenset({2, 3}), frozenset({1})}
```

Which (except for the ordering) should be exactly what you want.

Comment: Instead of a fixed `range`, you can "unpack" all data and iterate them `set.union(*data)`